# python delete list from another list

Tags: python, list, set, frozenset

There're two lists like

```
[[A, A], [B, B], [C, C], [D, D]]
```

and

```
[[A, A], [B, B]]
```

How to delete list 2 from 1 with result `[[C, C], [D, D]]` and make it without loop, because both lists are very big and loops works slow?

thanks
list examples

```
>>>a = [[9, 9], [8, 8], [7, 7], [6, 6], [4, 4], [5, 5], [12, 12], [15, 15], [2, 2], [3, 3]] 

>>>b = [[4, 4], [5, 5]]
```

form ask to write what I already tried, OK, it's below
Attempt one: (doesn't work, moreover has a loop inside)

```
def rightdotsremowe (ax, bx): 
    for o in set(bx):
        try:
            ax.remove(o) 
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return ax
```

Attempt two (looks better but doesn't work too)

```
newlist00 = [x for x in a if (x not in e)]
```

Comment: If they were sets of tuples you could just subtract them, but I don't see how to do this without loops (meaning, in less than O(n)) with a 2D list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order is not very important to you,`sets` are significantly faster. So you can try this,it will be faster than list.

```
a=[['A', 'A'], ['B', 'B'], ['C', 'C'], ['D', 'D']]

a={tuple(i) for i in a}
```

And try to use `difference` method:

> return new set with elements in a but not in b

**Average case O(len(a))**

```
a=[['A', 'A'], ['B', 'B'], ['C', 'C'], ['D', 'D']]
b=[['A', 'A'], ['B', 'B']]

a={tuple(i) for i in a}
b={tuple(i) for i in b}

print a.difference(b)
```

That is becaus `set` uses a hash function to map to a bucket. Since Python implementations automatically resize that hash table, the speed can be constant `O(1)`.

`Sets` are significantly faster when it comes to determining if an object in a set , but slower than `lists` when it comes to iterating over their contents.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Making a set doesn't magically make things faster. Set _lookups_ are O(1). This also doesn't address the filtering aspect at all.

Answer (score 0):

Just convert the items you want to remove to set of tuples and then use list comprehension to create a new list:

```
>>> a = [[9, 9], [8, 8], [7, 7], [6, 6], [4, 4], [5, 5], [12, 12], [15, 15], [2, 2], [3, 3]]
>>> b = [[4, 4], [5, 5]]
>>> s = {tuple(x) for x in b}
>>> [x for x in a if tuple(x) not in s]
[[9, 9], [8, 8], [7, 7], [6, 6], [12, 12], [15, 15], [2, 2], [3, 3]]
```

Above has **O(n)** time complexity since checking membership in set is **O(1)** where as using only lists has **O(n^2)** time complexity since membership testing in list is **O(n)**. Note that it works only if items on the lists are [hashable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html).

Comment: All this does is check for membership in a set rather than a list. The OP already tried almost exactly this, and said that it "doesn't work" (for some unspecified reason).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 That's the whole point, membership checking with `set` has **O(1)** time complexity where as list is **O(n)**. Added short explanation about time complexities to the answer to stress the point.

Comment: If you know what the "whole point" is, please let me know. OP just said that what they tried "doesn't work." I don't know if they mean it produces an error, has incorrect results, is too slow, or what.

Answer (score 0):

```
[obj for obj in a if obj not in b]
```

Comment: use 'b' instead of 'e' in [x for x in a if (x not in e)]. It should work then

Comment: I have no idea where the `e` came from. The OP never said what "didn't work" about it, so we can only guess. If it's a simple typo, then an answer isn't necessary, as that kind of question isn't useful. If it's something else, then this answer doesn't add anything that wasn't present in the question.

Comment: you right, its my fault. "e" comes from attempt to understand what's wrong in stroke and means e= [5, 5] where I tried to make list 2 more simple, without list inside